# express handlebars | how I get the map value

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js, mongoose-populate

controller.js

```
Settings.find()
.then((result) => {
   for(const key in result){
       const map = new Map();
       map.set(result[key].key,result[key].value);
   }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

res.render('admin/settings', {
    data : this.map
});
```

how can i send map value to view? what should i do about it?

view.js

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="config_site_title" value="config_site_title">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
const getIndex = async (req, res, next) => {
    Settings.find()
    .then((result) => {
       for(const key in result){
            
           const data = new Array();
           data.push(result[key].key,result[key].value);
           console.log(data);
           res.render('admin/settings', {
            pageDetails: {
                title: "Yönetim Paneli - Ayarlar",
            },
            data : data
        });
       }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).